# How would I texture this lamp, especially the lamp shade?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

[image: lamp object in blender]

How should I texture this lamp so it looks like this?
[image: lamp reference image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: lamp shade rendered in cycles]

It's Surprisingly simple. Just an image texture, for the pattern (like [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/digitalartform/4056362689)) and a [Translucent BSDF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/translucent.html) node.  The trick is to put a lamp inside the shade (where the light bulb would go in real life.)

[image: cycles nodes]

The *layer weight* node is how I made the darker edges. The *RGB Curves* node, inverts and changes the slope of the fresnel. Then the *ColorRamp* node is just to tone down the black (I'm using 0.05, instead of pure black).
The bottom three nodes are just the standard image texture nodes. The shade texture (a black and white image) get multiplied with the fresnel, and all that is plugged into the *Translucent* node. Next trick is the *Mix Shader* node with an empty socket. That is just making the whole material darker.